# How to pick a class in Mass Effect 3 on Xbox One?

Tags: mass-effect-3, xbox-one

It turns out ME3 is backwards-compatible with Xbox One. However, you never see the dialogue to change the type of the player and you always start with a Soldier type whereas a prefer a biotic.

Does this choice come later or what do I do?

Comment: How are you starting a game? Are you starting a new game with a new Shepard, or are you importing a savegame? Normally it should ask you to select your class during character creation.

Comment: If I recall correctly there's also some kind of option for starting the game as the ["default" Shepard](http://cultspark.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Mass-Effect-default-Shepard.jpg) (sets his appearance, name, **class**, etc.).  Maybe you're starting the game using that default setting as default Shepard is a soldier.  Although this may have just been a setting in the first Mass Effect.

Comment: I saw said dialog, are you sure it's missing?

Comment: There should definitely be an option for default character or custom character. I recall such an option on every Mass Effect. The default is indeed a soldier. I would have to boot it up to see the exact text.